# How do I find the intersection of two polylines in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, google-maps, routing, line

I have a set of road conditions reported for small segments of road, and I am hoping to determine the specific subset of each segment which intersect with a route along the road so that I can draw the intersection of the route and road conditions on a map.

Is there a way to determine the specific points of intersection of two polylines in PostGIS in a way suitable for plotting on a Google Map?

I am new to PostGIS so please accept my apologize if I am getting any terminology wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[St_Intersection](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) function will give you the a point/collection of points that are the intersection of two linestrings. `ST_Intersects` can be used to find linestrings that intersect.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that function a try once I've got my data loaded in. Is there a tolerance when a point is considered "close enough" to overlap or do the points need to be identical to match?

Comment: There is no tolerance, you can use `ST_Buffer` to make the lines "thicker" but then you'd have to choose what point you want to represent the intersection.